# how do i change only one word in excel-vba array

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim T As Variant, ReT As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    T = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
    ReT = Array("one", "two", "three", "Four", "five", "six", "seven")

    For i = 0 To UBound(T)
         Columns("K:O").ReplaceT (i), ReT(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

excel list

```
1fbb(1)
2cbc(1)
5ddf(3)
5asd(6)
.
.
.
```

I want to get :

```
onefbb(1),twocbc(1),fiveddf(3),fiveasd(6) ...
```

but it result is...

```
onefdd(one),twocbc(one),fiveddf(three),fiveasd(six) ...
```

it`s all greek to me plz help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I got one for you:

```
Public Sub replaceNumber()

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Sheets("sheetname").Range("K1:O10")

        cell.Value = getWords(Left(cell.Value, 1)) & Mid(cell.Value, 2)

    Next cell

End Sub

Private Function getWords(number As String)

    Dim numbers, words As Variant
    Dim index As Long

    numbers = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
    words = Array("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven")

    For index = 0 To UBound(numbers)

        If number = numbers(index) Then

            getWords = words(index)
            Exit For

        End If

    Next index

End Function
```

In my code, I separate a function to get the word for number.

I use as **`Sheets("sheetname").Range("K1:O10")`**, so, you should change `sheetname` to your sheet name. And I used fixed range **`K1:O10`** because we can't use `Columns("K:O")` while looping cell. It can harm the application.

So, please change that Range according to your input data. I already tested about the code and it work well for me. If it has any problem, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want, I am assuming the following:

There is only a value up to 7 at the start (well it would work up to 9, any single digit number really)

You have not explicitly set option base to 1, if you have then remove the `-1` in the code:

```
Sub ChangeFirstChar()
Dim cell As Range, ret As Variant
ret = Array("one", "two", "three", "Four", "five", "six", "seven")
For Each cell In Range("K1:O" & Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    cell.Formula = ret(CLng(Left(cell.text, 1)) - 1) & Right(cell.text, Len(cell.text) - 1)
Next
End Sub
```

It works because your array addresses can be a direct reference (-1) from the number at the start of the value.